# using static_cast to convert char to int c++

Tags: c++

I want to use static_cast to convert char to int.

> 2. Write a program inputs a character (char). Then using a type conversion (static_cast) print out the integer value of the letter.  What happens if you add 1 to a character variable?  Print out the results.

```
char main()
{
    char n;
    cout << "Enter a character: ";  
    static_cast<n>(int + 1);
    return n;
    system("pause");
}
```

I'm really new to C++ and my book hasn't come in yet, yet my homework is due Sunday, so any help on these too would be much appreciated.

> 3. Write a program that converts meters to feet (3.279 feet per meter).  Your program must take meters as input (i.e. 3.25) and convert to feet (i.e. 10.657).  Output the results.
> 4. Write a program that calculates compounding interest (futureValue = presentValue * (1 + interestRate)numberOfYears.  To raise a number to a power, use the pow() command.  To use pow() you must also include the cmath library in your program (#include <cmath>).  The format is as follows:
>
>    pow( <value>, <power> )
>      FutureValue = PresentValue * pow( (1 +InterestRate), Years );
>
>    If the interest rate is 6% and your present value is $200, how long will it take to double your money (future value is greater than or equal to $400)?

Comment: Unless you can provide a referenced tot the standard proving different, `static_cast` is not C, so don't spam tags!

Comment: also, main() should return `int`, your mcve is not correct, the program doesn't compile, and it's got a useless pause after return ...

Comment: It's hard to know where to begin, there are many mistakes in your example. To directly answer the title's question, the usage of `static_cast` you are looking for is `int i = static_cast<int>(n);`. It's incorrect to believe `static_cast` can be used to change the type of a variable. For example, you cannot change `n`'s type to `int`. The best you can do is convert `n`'s value to `int` and store the result in a new `int` variable.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework service. These are questions you should be asking your instructor. That being said, your code is not following the requirements of the assignment at all. You are not reading input from the user at all. Even if you were, you are not casting and incrementing it correctly, you are using the wrong syntax, so the code will not compile. And you are not outputting the results at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with this code.

- The interface to main isn't one of the legal possibilities. It should return `int`.
- You're mixing up your type and your variable, your static cast should probably be

  > ```
  > static_cast<int>(n + 1)
  > ```
- You're not doing anything with the result of the static cast. Normally it would be used in an assignment or passed to a function.

Comment: could you elaborate a little further. I'm having just one more problem with my code where it is saying char n: redefinition.